# Android Flashlight force closing on return from other activity

Tags: android, logcat, forceclose, flashlight

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/) and managed to implement the flash light into my app. However I have come unstuck.

The flash light button works wonders upon first load of the app, but when you go to another activity (page) and then come back to the first activity (page) and try to use the flash light button it force closes the app

Here is the logCat I loaded the app, turned torch on and off navigated to another activity and back then tried the flash light again and bam dead

```
08-18 23:12:50.854: I/info(10685): torch is turn on!
08-18 23:12:51.565: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004001
08-18 23:12:51.565: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
08-18 23:12:51.565: I/info(10685): torch is turn off!
08-18 23:12:58.522: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004001
08-18 23:12:58.522: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
08-18 23:12:58.672: D/ATRecorder(10685): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4054f238
08-18 23:12:58.682: D/WindowManagerImpl(10685): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40545f00
08-18 23:12:58.912: D/Camera-JNI(10685): native_release: context=0x34cec0 camera=0x34ce78
08-18 23:13:00.844: W/KeyCharacterMap(10685): Can't open keycharmap file
08-18 23:13:00.854: W/KeyCharacterMap(10685): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/synaptics-rmi-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='synaptics-rmi-touchscreen'
08-18 23:13:00.854: I/KeyCharacterMap(10685): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-18 23:13:01.214: D/WindowManagerImpl(10685): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40545f00
08-18 23:13:02.205: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004001
08-18 23:13:02.205: D/View(10685): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
08-18 23:13:02.205: I/info(10685): torch is turn on!
08-18 23:13:02.205: D/AndroidRuntime(10685): Shutting down VM
08-18 23:13:02.205: W/dalvikvm(10685): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:958)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at com.reading.festival.ReadingFestivalGuide2012Activity$1.onClick(ReadingFestivalGuide2012Activity.java:84)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-18 23:13:02.215: E/AndroidRuntime(10685):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code used for camera

```
private boolean isLighOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //makes full screen and takes away title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //



        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (isLighOn) {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isLighOn = false;

                } else {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLighOn = true;

                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called `camera.setparameters()` after calling `camera.release()`. 
You should not call setparameters after releasing it.

Comment: ok so after removing the camera release it works fine between activities however surly it needs a camera release somewhere or camera wont be able to be used. How can i set it so that when you bring the home activity to the front it releases the camera

Comment: no didn't work, reinstating the camera.release(); crashes the app when it comes back from other activities any other ideas.

Comment: move camera.open() to onresume, and camera.release in onpause

Comment: sorry very novice can you elaborate further please

Comment: i have not seen your code but i hope you are doing camera.open()? move it to onresume function of the activity and camera.release() to onpause function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15524/discussion-between-nandeesh-and-tim-hannah)